# Fody Costura c++ runtime

Tags: c#, fody, fody-costura

My c# program uses a dll written in c++, and this dll is embedded by Fody Costura.

It works on machines having Visual C++ runtime installed or having `msvcp140.dll` and dependencies in the working folder.

Is it possible to embed `msvcp140.dll` and dependencies to the executable using Fody Costura? My attempt to do it was unsuccessful.

Comment: You probably should add some details on your attempt to do so. I'm not familiar with Fody Costura, so I can't help you with that, but try to keep these details as minimal as possible (something close to a [MCVE])

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to embed msvcp140.dll and dependencies to the executable using Fody Costura?

Yes.

**Option 1: Use the dependency files on the working directory**

Refer to the official document for [Unmanaged32Assemblies & Unmanaged64Assemblies](https://github.com/Fody/Costura#unmanaged32assemblies--unmanaged64assemblies)
 config option

**Option 2: Use the installed Visual C++ runtime**

Add a code to check if the required version of the Visual C++ runtime is installed before using the C++ library